# The Attendance data by excel file imported into the attendance module have been lost in Odoo 13. How to fix it?

Tags: excel, import, module, odoo, time-and-attendance

I have successfully imported the attendance data into attendance data of 11/13/2019 by excel file.

[image]

And I have successfully imported the attendance data of next day too.

[image]

But the data of day 13 have been lost as you can see.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you add a sample of both excel files?

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved.

[image]

As you can see. I selected External ID before importing. It will overwrite the data and the previous data will be lost!